# Children don't re-render when parent shouldComponentUpdate() always returns false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Parent's state changes, but childs never re-render himself.

```
class Parent extends Component<{}, {isSelected: boolean}> {    
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            isSelected: false
        }
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false
    }

    onClick = () => {
        this.setState( (state) => {
            return {isSelected: !this.state.isSelected}
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Button onClick={this.onClick}>
                <Child isSelected={this.state.isSelected}/>
            </Button>
        )
    }
}
```

I understand that shouldComponentUpdate() doesn't affect the re-rendering of its children, so why are the children not re-rendering? (if I remove shouldComponentUpdate() everything works as expected)

Comment: `onPress` class method is undefined as of this writing in your example

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` *does* affect children. If the parent doesn't re-render, it won't pass the new `isSelected` value to the child. If the child doesn't get a new prop, it won't re-render

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973 Fixed, my bad. I re-write the code for the question and miss that.